# What does 'Move over' mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

How to uderstand is 'Move over' phrasial verb or not and what does it mean here?

> World's Latest Healthiest Diet (**Move Over** Mediterranean!)

I also would like to sea the link of the meaning in dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Move over" is often used to denote that a former leading person or thing has been beaten or exceeded by a newcomer. E.g. "Move over, Rolls-Royce, Lexus is the new leading brand of luxury car". The "Mediterranean diet" has been considered by many to be one of the world's healthiest diets. Presumably the writer of what you were reading is reporting a new diet which is alleged to be more healthy. You can interpret "move over" to mean "vacate the leader's place".

Move over Elon Musk - this robot crab could be the world's most surreal invention.

Move Over Bill Gates, Everyday People Are Becoming Philanthropists

> move over (or aside)
>
> 1.1 Relinquish a job or leading position through being superseded by someone or something else.

[Move (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/move)

Comment: Now I understand the meaning, but your examples are not enough clear for me: Move Over Bill Gates, Everyday People Are Becoming Philanthropists

Comment: Bill Gates' philanthropy was considered very newsworthy. The headline writer was suggesting that the philanthropy of "everyday people" is equally interesting, or more so.,

Answer (score 0):

A Mediterranean diet (lots of vegetables and fish,for example) has long been considered a healthy diet.

In English, the phrase: Move over is used when you want to sit on a couch or bench (for example) and there is enough room for you but people sitting there are taking up all the space. To sit down yourself, you would therefore say to those people: Move over so I can sit down. Of course, you can say "Please move over,"also.

So, in the text in the question, the author is being humorous. He is addressing the diet **as if it were a person**, because she or he wants to "sit down", which in this case means he wants to present some other diet as the one that is best and that should have a space for itself.

It is an image used in what one can call marketing "speak".